# Xively works locally but not from server

Tags: json, xively

Yes, the question has been asked, but it's not answered in a way that I'm able to apply to my situation, so I'm asking again. Arduino uploads to Xively and then I'm hoping to download to a mobile site I'm toying around with. Works just fine locally, but when I upload it to the server, I get nothing.

The site is here...
http://ryecrowendesign.com/xivelyTEMP/tempBedroom1.html

The temperature should appear in the circle. You can ignore the other items.

Thanks so much. I've spent so much time on this already.

Cheers,
~Rye

Comment: Well I'm not a Javascript expert, which is really what you need here. However, I looked through your code on the linked website and it looks like you have the script commented out of the HTML. I also looked through the network calls, and I see that you load Jquery and XivelyJS correctly, but I don't actually see any network calls to api.xively.com. So there is some issue with the way you are using XivelyJS. It might be helpful if you posted your code, so someone with Javascript expertise can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good idea to post the code. I thought that the Xively.JS file was making the call to api, but my limited knowledge of javascript can't confirm that.